# Using the method of looping, write a program to print the table of 9 till N

Tags: javascript

**Sample Input:**

```
3
```

**Sample Output:**

```
9 18 27
```

What i did :

```
var N = +userInput[0];
var b = [];

if (N === 0) {
  console.log('NULL');
} else {
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) {
  b.push(i);
}

var c = b.map(b => b * 9);
console.log(c);
```

I get `[9, 18, 27]` as my output and I can't figure out how to change it to `9 18 27`

Comment: How should the result be 87?

Comment: if you want the result to be a string you can just join them with a space `c.join(' ')`

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry i edited it to 27 now

Comment: @Reyno thanks a ton! it works cant believe i missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `join` to transform the array into a string:

```js
var N = 3;
var b = [];

if (N === 0) {
  console.log('NULL');
} else {
  for (i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) {
    b.push(i);
  }
}

var c = b.map(b => b * 9);
console.log(c.join(' '));
```